# Laravel Telescope Schedule not worked on localhost(mac)

Tags: laravel

I want test laravel telescope on mac localhost

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('inspire')
                  ->everyMinute();
}
```

and

```
* * * * * cd /Users/Jon/Desktop/laravel && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

> We didn't find anything - just empty space.

but not worked on my system

Answer (score 0):

`>> /dev/null` redirects standard output (`stdout`) to `/dev/null`, which discards it.
So you cannot find anything.

You can add output to a file:

```php
$schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```

or

```php
* * * * * cd /Users/Jon/Desktop/laravel && php artisan schedule:run  >> /tmp/file.txt
```